# Python 3.2 tkinter create a results frame to display output

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, frame

I currently have a working menu test for my restaurant that reads input received by checkbuttons, compares them to correct answers and then displays either a ***good job*** messagebox or a ***keep working*** messagebox.  I also have it set up so that if they do not get the questions right, it prints what they answered followed by the correct answer.  Instead of the message boxes and simply printing what they did wrong I would like to have a final ***results*** screen that either has a good job (or something along those lines) message or has the printed wrong vs correct answers on it.  Here is my code to show you how I have implemented everything so far, like I said everything is working I am just trying to figure out a way to make it more presentable and haven't been able to find a way to do this.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox as tkMessageBox
class GUI(Frame):

def __init__(self, parent):
    Frame.__init__(self, parent)    
    self.parent = parent
    self.initUI()
    self.count = -1
    self.answers = {'nft':[], 'nckt':[]}
    self.menuItems = {'nft': ['Cheese', 'Cabbage', 'Corn', 'Blackened Fish', 'Salsa'],
    'nckt': ['Lettuce', 'Cheese', 'Corn', 'Blackened Chicken', 'Salsa']}
    self.menu = ['nft', 'nckt']
    #self.p = PhotoImage(file="wahoos.gif")
    #self.l = Label(self, image=self.p).grid(row=7, column=7)
def initUI(self):
    self.grid() 
    self.parent.title("Wahoos Menu Test")
    self.create_buttons() 


def create_buttons(self):
    for r in range(20):
        for c in range(14):
            Label(self, text='',
                borderwidth=0).grid(row=r,column=c)
    self.b = Button(self, text ="Begin Exam", relief=RIDGE, fg="black", command= self.on_button_press)
    self.b.grid(row=19, column=7)
    self.m = Label(self, text="")
    self.m.grid(row=7, column=0)
    L = Label(self, text="What comes in the following", fg="blue").grid(row=6, column=0)
    self.tortButton = {'Flour':0, 'Corn':0, 'Wheat':0}
    self.vegButton = {'Lettuce':0, 'Cabbage':0, 'Cheese':0,
        'Ahee Rice':0, 'Brown Rice':0, 'Banzai Veg':0, 'Red Cabbage':0, 'Beans':0}
    self.protButton = {'Carne Asada':0, 'Flamebroiled Chicken':0, 'Blackened Fish':0,
        'Blackened Chicken':0, 'Flamebroiled Fish':0, 'Pork':0, 'Shrimp':0,
        'Tofu':0, 'Blackened Mushroom':0, 'Rice and Beans':0, 'Banzai Veggies':0}
    self.sauceButton = {'Salsa':0, 'Guacamole':0, 'Sour Cream':0,
        'Roasted Pepper':0, 'Ketchup':0, 'Ranch':0, 'Balsamic':0,
        'Mr. Lees':0, 'Teriyaki':0, 'Tapatio':0, 'Cream Cheese':0, 'Aioli':0}
    V = Label(self, text="Veggies", fg="green").grid(row=1, column=11, sticky=W)
    T = Label(self, text="Tortillas     ", fg="green").grid(row=1, column=12, sticky=W)
    P = Label(self, text="Proteins", fg="green").grid(row=1, column=13, sticky=W)
    S = Label(self, text="Sauces", fg="green").grid(row=1, column=14, sticky=W)
    c = 1
    for key in self.tortButton:
        c +=1
        self.tortButton[key] = IntVar()
        to = Checkbutton(self, text=key, variable=self.tortButton[key]).grid(row=c, column=12, sticky=W)
    c = 1
    for key in self.vegButton:
        c += 1
        self.vegButton[key] = IntVar()
        vo = Checkbutton(self, text=key, variable=self.vegButton[key]).grid(row=c, column=11, sticky=W)         
    c = 1
    for key in self.protButton:
        c +=1
        self.protButton[key] = IntVar()
        po = Checkbutton(self, text=key, variable=self.protButton[key]).grid(row=c, column=13, sticky=W)
    c = 1
    for key in self.sauceButton:
        c +=1
        self.sauceButton[key] = IntVar()
        so = Checkbutton(self, text=key, variable=self.sauceButton[key]).grid(row=c, column=14, sticky=W)

def on_button_press(self):
    self.count = self.count + 1
    if self.count == len(self.menu):
        self.m.configure(text="")
        self.b.configure(text ="Your Done!  Click here to see your results.", command = self.compare)
    else:
        self.m.configure(text=self.menu[self.count])
        self.b.configure(text ="Submit and Continue", command= self.read_checks)
def read_checks(self):
    for key, value in self.vegButton.items():
        state = value.get()
        if state !=0:
            print (key)
            self.answers[self.menu[self.count]].append(key)
            self.vegButton[key].set(0)
    for key, value in self.tortButton.items():
        state = value.get()
        if state !=0:
            print (key)
            self.answers[self.menu[self.count]].append(key)
            self.tortButton[key].set(0)
    for key, value in self.protButton.items():
        state = value.get()
        if state !=0:
            print (key)
            self.answers[self.menu[self.count]].append(key)
            self.protButton[key].set(0)
    for key, value in self.sauceButton.items():
        state = value.get()
        if state !=0:
            print (key)
            self.answers[self.menu[self.count]].append(key)
            self.sauceButton[key].set(0)
    print (self.answers)
    print (self.menuItems)
    self.on_button_press()
def compare(self):
    self.match = True
    self.count = -1     
    for key in self.answers:
        if self.answers[key] != self.menuItems[key]:
            print ("For ", self.menu[self.count], " you answered ", self.answers[key])
            print ("The correct answer for ", self.menu[self.count], " is ", self.menuItems[key])
            self.count = self.count + 1
            self.match = False
    if self.match == True:
        tkMessageBox.showinfo("All Pau!", "Nice job!  I think your ready!")
    else:
        tkMessageBox.showinfo("Uh Ohh", "Looks like you have some more studying to do.")
def main():
    root = Tk()
    app = GUI(root)
    root.mainloop()
if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

`def compare(self)` is where I do my comparisons and print the output that I would like to appear on the results screen, this is also where I have the messageboxes pop up.

Comment: I was reading the code on some of the other questions you posted. The design of your code is very procedural--it seems like you could do well with a more data oriented approach. Rather than approaching the program step-by-step, why don't you build self-contained, generic objects for each separate task, and then "glue" them together. It would allow you to reuse more code, save on typing, and in the end make your program much more readable.

Comment: I agree with you there, I am new to python and this is the first major thing I have actually coded with it so for the time being I am just learning everything as I go along and then plan on going back through and cleaning it up, separating the logic from the GUI and all of that.   Thanks for the comment though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd have the GUI inherit from Tk,
and then put the different "windows" in Frames.
You could then use `grid_forget()`, or `destroy()`, on a Frame to make it disappear.
Use `grid()` on a frame to make it reappear, if you chose to not destroy it.
Here's a simplified demonstration,
where the original frame (aFrame) reappears after 3000ms of displaying the result frame (rFrame).
See the `result_screen` and `go_back` methods at the bottom:

```
import tkinter as tk

class GUI(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)

        self.score = 0

        self.buttonDic = {
        'Brown Rice':0,
        'Banzai Veg':0,
        'Red Cabbage':0,
        'Black Beans':0
        }

        aFrame = self.aFrame = tk.Frame(self)
        aFrame.grid()

        for key in self.buttonDic:
            self.buttonDic[key] = tk.IntVar()
            aCheckButton = tk.Checkbutton(aFrame, text=key,
                                            variable=self.buttonDic[key])
            aCheckButton.grid(sticky='w')

        submitButton = tk.Button(aFrame, text="Submit",
                                        command=self.query_checkbuttons)
        submitButton.grid()

        self.trueList = ['Brown Rice', 'Black Beans']

    def query_checkbuttons(self):
        for key, value in self.buttonDic.items():
            state = value.get()
            if state != 0:
                if key in self.trueList:
                    self.score += 1
                else:
                    self.score -= 1
                self.buttonDic[key].set(0)
        self.result_screen()

    def result_screen(self):
        self.aFrame.grid_forget()
        self.rFrame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.rFrame.grid()
        self.scoreText = tk.Text(self.rFrame, width=20, height=1)
        self.scoreText.grid()
        self.scoreText.insert('end', self.score)
        self.after(3000, func=self.go_back)

    def go_back(self):
        self.score = 0
        self.rFrame.destroy()
        self.aFrame.grid()


gui = GUI()
gui.mainloop()
```

Comment: thanks so much for your response!  I was able to make it work using this approach.  Is it possible however to print the output I was originally printing to the command line to the new frame? I have tried a bunch of different things and cant seem to make anything work?  I can obviously get it to print multiple lines or however many I need, but I cant figure out how to print the keys and values from the dictionaries themselves...?

Comment: @crenfro Anything you can print could be inserted into a Text widget, as far as I know. You could try formatting the string before, and then put that variable in the insert() method. I'd need to see your current example to say anything more, and that would technically be a separate question / answer.

Comment: Ahh you know what I was using the StringVar() in the wrong way.  I got it to work.  Thanks again!!